# Why does PyCharm incorrectly guess type for a list of dict_items?

Tags: python, pycharm, typing

For this piece of code:

```
from typing import Dict, List, Tuple, Any


def test(d: Dict[int, Any]):
    item_list: List[Tuple[int, Any]] = list(d.items())
```

PyCharm guesses that `item_list` will be of type `List[int]` for some reason:

[image: PyCharm screenshot]

Am I missing something or this is quite an easy case of deducing the type and PyCharm is in the wrong here?

Comment: Strange indeed. Seems a bug. It works as expected with `= [pair for pair in d.items()]`.

Comment: @trincot Yea, that's what I thought. Thanks for confirming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct. It's a bug in PyCharm. 
You can track its status on their bug tracker here: 
[Incorrect type inference of dict.items()](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30709). Consider voting on it so it will be fixed sooner.